# in typescript, is there a way to prevent implicit dependencies on builtin functions and globals

Tags: typescript, dependencies, eslint, compiler-warnings, built-in

I would like it if my typescript compiler or eslinter raises an error if I use any builtin function or global variable without importing it explicitly.
Can this be done and if so, how?

for example

```
//missing: import { console, process, Array } from "?"

export function print(): number[] {
    console.log("Hello") //this console usage should raise an error
    process.stdout.write("World!") //this process usage too
    return new Array<number>() //ideally this Array constructor too
}
```

Comment: You could use eslint `no-undef`: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef to prevent accessing implicit scope. (but not buili-ins as far as I know)

Comment: I did not use https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noLib but it looks like the best option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noLib

> Disables the automatic inclusion of any library files. If this option is set, lib is ignored.
>
> TypeScript cannot compile anything without a set of interfaces for key primitives like: Array, Boolean, Function, IArguments, Number, Object, RegExp, and String. It is expected that if you use noLib you will be including your own type definitions for these.